# Force cmake to fail a build over unmet conditions

Tags: configuration, cmake

I would like to force my `cmake` based configuration to fail ( and possibly print a message ) if:

- there are unused variables ( which are likely to be a typo in most cases )
- there are unused modules ( same thing as before or useless stuff )
- a particular `if` is not being evaluated to `TRUE`

I find that the fact that `cmake` is macro based solution makes it hard to spot errors on big projects, so if someone has some some hints on that. Basically `cmake` doesn't alert you because anything could be a custom variable and not necessarily a typo or a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Let's address your points out-of-order.

> a particular if is not being evaluated to TRUE

The way to achieve this is a [`FATAL_ERROR` message](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/message.html):

```
if(SOME_CONDITION)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "You did something wrong!")
endif()
```

> there are unused variables

This is more difficult. There are the [`--warn-unused-vars`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#opt%3a--warn-unused-vars) and [`--warn-uninitialized`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#opt%3a--warn-uninitialized) command line options, but this has to be given by the user when running CMake. It is not possible to enforce this behavior from within a CMake script.

Also, there is no way to turn these warnings into fatal errors: CMake will still try to produce a valid Makefile (and may succeed in doing so). The only viable solution here seems to be developer discipline: Whenever a developer makes changes to the build environment, they should be aware of this compile options and check their code accordingly. Just as you would do with your other source code.

If you have trouble enforcing this, try to provide a shell-script as a wrapper that already sets all of the desired command line options. While not perfect, this will at least remove the obstruction of *having to look up that damn parameter in the manual* for your developers.

> there are unused modules

This is not possible, but I also don't see a big problem here. Worst thing that can happen is that pulling in the module adds some noise to the cached variables, but none of that would have any influence on the final generated build files.

CMake modules should always be kept small enough so that pulling them in should have no noticeable impact on the runtime of your CMake configure run.